# c++ string capacity change during copy assignment

Tags: c++, string, g++, capacity

In the C++ Standard `std:string` follows an exponential growth policy, therefore I suppose the `capacity()` of string during concatenation will always be increased when necessary. However, when I test `test.cpp`, I found that in the for-loop, **only every two times** will the `capacity()` be shrunk back to `length()` during assignment.

Why isn't this behavior depending on the length of string, but depending on how frequent I change the string? Is it some kind of optimization?

The following codes are tested with `g++ -std=c++11`.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>  
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::string s = "";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    //s += "*";
    s = s + "*";
    std::cout << s.length() << " " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And the output will be like this:

```
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 4
5 8
6 6    // why is capacity shrunk?
7 12
8 8    // and again?
9 16
10 10  // and again?
11 20
12 12  // and again?
13 24
14 14  // and again?
15 28
16 16  // and again?
17 32
...
996 996
997 1992
998 998  // and again?
999 1996
1000 1000  // and again?
```

Comment: Now I guess I don't understand your question. Is it "why would copy assignment ever reduce capacity?" If so, isn't the answer pretty obvious?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know this previously, but abarnert tells us that "When copy-assigning from one string to another, there's no reason to copy the capacity" ? My problem is that, the copy assignment doesn't always reduce capacity, but only do that every two times.

Comment: You could simply look at the source code for your compiler's implementation of `std::string` and see why it does what it does.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
s = s + "*";
```

You're doing two separate things: making a new temporary string, consisting of `"*"` concatenated onto the end of the contents `s`, and then copy-assigning that new string to `s`.

It's not the `+` that's shrinking, it's the `=`. When copy-assigning from one string to another, there's no reason to copy the capacity, just the actual used bytes.

Your commented-out code does this:

```
s += "*";
```

… is only doing one thing, appending `"*"` onto the end of `s`. So, there's nowhere for the "optimization" to happen (if it happened, it would be a *pessimization*, defeating the entire purpose of the exponential growth).

Comment: "When copy-assigning from one string to another, there's no reason to copy the capacity, just the actual used bytes." - that doesn't actually account for the observed behaviour.  For C++11 it makes sense for a move assignment to swap buffers, so the assigned-to object takes on the capacity of the temporary; for C++03 the assignment *could* copy used bytes, but then you wouldn't expect the capacity to be reduced - that would only happen for implementations using reference counting that discard the current larger-capacity buffer (i.e. *not* doing your "copy [of] actual used bytes".

Comment: Anyway - +1 for pointing out the crucial difference between `+` and `+=` and the importance of the temporary.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not convered by the C++ standard what happens to `capacity()` when strings are moved, assigned, etc. This could be a defect.   The only constraints are those derivable from the time complexity specified for the operation.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253355/what-happens-to-the-underlying-storage-upon-vectors-copy-move-assignment) for similar discussion about vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's helpful.