# Do I need to call clear() when I am done with a vector?

Tags: c++, memory-management

All of the questions that I have seen ask about managing memory when the *elements* of the vector are dynamically allocated/are pointers. My question is just about a vector that has been allocated on the stack, with a simple type, for example, `int`.

If I have the following code:

```
std::vector<int> vec(5);
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Do I need to call `clear()` when I am done?

Comment: Take a look at destructors. When the vector goes out of scope, it will be deallocated for you! This is one of the many reasons you've probably also seen people on this site preaching vectors over dynamically allocated arrays :)

Comment: `clear()` is unneeded.

Comment: Elements of `std::vector` are always dynamically allocated, independently of whether the vector object itself is on the stack or on the heap (small buffer optimization cannot be used due to Standard constraints). Destruction of elements and deallocation of buffer is done automatically in destructor following RAII idiom, employed by all STL containers.

Comment: You don't need to do that. class Vector achieves RAII.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No.

Classes in C++ have a destructor that gets called when the class object goes out of scope or is deleted. While you are correct that `std::vector` dynamically allocates space under the hood, the `std::vector` destructor will deallocate the memory for you resulting in a happy leak-free program.

From the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/%7Evector), when the vector destructor is called it...

> Destructs the container. The destructors of the elements are called and the used storage is deallocated. Note, that if the elements are pointers, the pointed-to objects are not destroyed.

---

Also note that from the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) on clear, the function...

> Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged...

So when you call `clear` the memory isn't even actually being free'd! (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467624/what-does-the-standard-say-about-how-calling-clear-on-a-vector-changes-the-capac/18467916#18467916) for more on what `clear` is actually doing)

Comment: _"if the elements are pointers, the pointed-to objects are not destroyed"_ This is valid for raw pointers only, not for smart ones. Just for clarification.

Comment: @DanielLangr To be fair, smart pointers aren't seen as pointer types from the language's point of view.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Agree, they are ordinary classes.

Answer (score 7):

If you are worried about freeing the memory allocated (and hence blocked for use elsewhere) in a (large) `vector`, you should

1. make sure the scope/lifetime of the respective vector is limited to the region/time of its imminent use, so that its destruction automatically frees the memory.
2. failing that (for whatever reason), you may

   ```
   vec.clear();          // reduces the size to 0, but not the capacity
   vec.shrink_to_fit();  // suggests to reduce the capacity to size
   assert(vec.capacity()==0);
   ```

Note that [`vector::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) de-allocates no memory in `vector` (only memory, if any, dynamically allocated by the vector elements). [`vector::shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) suggests the reduction of the memory footprint of `vector` to its actual size, but the implementation can chose to ignore that request.

Finally, an alternative to `clear()` followed by `shrink_to_fit()` is the swap idiom (which also works prior to C++11):

```
vector<Tp>().swap(vec);
assert(vec.capacity()==0);
```

What happens here is that a new empty vector (of the same type) is constructed and then immediately swapped with `vec`, so that `vec` becomes empty (with zero size and capacity). Finally, because the new vector is a temporary (un-named) object, it is destructed, whereby de-allocating the memory originally kept with `vec`.

Comment: Or `std::vector<int>().swap(v);` if C++11 is not available.

Comment: @DanielLangr Good point. I shall add that to the answer.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's a pity that one cannot simply destroy the object via a direct destructor call (as this would invoke UB).

Comment: You can, but not for objects on the stack. If an object is created by placement new, then it's legal (`std::vector` does this internally with standard allocator; see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy).

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes I know. But I meant automatic variables, i.e. on the stack.

Comment: All right. I just clarified if someone else would read that without your assumption ;-)